# Excel Indirect function with Match

Tags: excel, indexing, match, excel-indirect

I am currently using the below formula which is returning an error.

What I am trying to do is select the entire column in the Price worksheet by using the indirect function and then return a value from that column based on 2 criteria's.
I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. Any help would be much appreciated.

=INDEX(INDIRECT("Prices!J2:J2"),MATCH(F5,Prices!B:B,0),MATCH(D5,Prices!A:A,0))

- **Prices!J2:J2** In cell J2 I have the column I want to reference in the Price
  worksheet
- **MATCH(F5,Prices!B:B,0),MATCH(D5,Prices!A:A,0)** I want to get a Price from the
  column referenced above where 2 conditions match.

The below code works for me but it is not robust. I'd like to get the INDIRECT working

```
=INDEX(Prices!BO:BO,MATCH(1,(D2=Prices!A:A)*(F2=Prices!$B:$B),0))
```

See error below:

[image: Error Message]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to look up the value from F2 in Column B and then return the corresponding entry in Column J. If so then this is the correct syntax:

```
=INDEX(Prices!J:J,MATCH(F2,Prices!B:B,0),1)
```

It also works if you add in INDIRECT:

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT("Prices!J:J"),MATCH(F2,Prices!B:B,0),1)
```

This website is a good reference for using index and match:

https://exceljet.net/index-and-match

Edit: some more relevant info from chat that helped the asker find his solution:

To make the "J" Column in the above formula adjustable from Cell F2, concatenate the address like so:

```
INDIRECT("Prices!"&J2&":"&J2)
```

So, if you put "C" in Cell J2, then INDIRECT will reference "Prices!C:C" and then INDEX will look up your data from Column C.

As for MATCH syntax, don't do this:

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT("Prices!"&J2&":"&J2),MATCH(1,(F3=Prices!B:B)‌​*(D3=Prices!$A:$A),0‌​))
```

Instead, concatenate F3 and D3, concatenate Column A and B data into Column A, and then do the MATCH, something like this:

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT("Prices!"&J2&":"&J2),MATCH(D3&F3,Prices!A:A​,0‌​))
```

Comment: Hi @Dharman, Thank you for the response unfortunately no luck. The formula I currently have is =INDEX(INDIRECT("Prices!J2:J2"),MATCH(F2,Prices!B:B)*(D5,Prices!A:A),0). This is not working for me and I'm not sure why. What I'm trying to do is: I have a column name e.g "M" typed in cell J2. I want to indirectly reference this column which is in another sheet and then look up a value based on 2 criteria's. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I been stuck on this issue all day.

Comment: I have this formula which is working =INDEX(Prices!G:G,MATCH(1,(F3=Prices!B:B)*(D3=Prices!$A:$A),0)). But when I add the indirect it won't work

Comment: Hi @bI33p bI00p, Unfortunately that didn't work either. I am getting a value error.

Comment: Is the indirect necessary about if we can just take the string from J2?

Comment: Nope entering "G" into cell J2 will not work. The error looks to be in the second match. I have posted a picture in the original question of the error.

Comment: Edit: deleted comments after continuing discussion in chat. Solution updated to provide more info in case it helps anyone else.